# Login Failure (Minecraft Launcher) with Qustodio

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

A little while ago I started experiencing a problem with my Minecraft launcher. I could only 'Play Offline', and when I tried to connect to a server I got an invalid session. Somewhere (I forgot where, sorry) some guy said to logout and log back in. I did this, and now I can't log back in. I get this message:

```
Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers.

Please make sure that you are online and that Minecraft is not blocked.

*(EOF Exception: SSL Peer shut down incorrectly)*
```

The launcher log from before I logged out is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/16580291/.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek that is about time. this is about SSL Peer. Different issues, really.

Comment: I don't think I have to ask this, but are you online?

Comment: And are you behind a work/school/public etc. network?

Comment: Like @ardaozkal said, you may be on a network that blocks Minecraft and should try to connect to another network.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek That is an entirely different question.

Comment: If you are on a home network, check your firewall settings and make sure Minecraft (i.e. `java.exe` and `javaw.exe`) is not blocked.

Comment: No. I'm connected to our home network and this just started happening. I'm using Win10, if that's of any use to you.

Comment: Do you have some kind of spyware program installed? Your parents might have a protection program maybe? I'm having the same problem, and I think that might have something to do with it because it's blocking the Minecraft Servers

Answer (score 4):

My son has qustodio and was having this same issue with Minecraft. I e-mailed qustodio customer service and was given a very quick response with a procedure that solved the problem! My son is now back to using Minecraft. I hope it works for you, here is the text from the e-mail:

> Hi, We have resolved the issue and reinstalling should address it. So,
>   can you please try again to install on your computer by following
>   these exact steps?
>
> - Uninstall any security suite from your computer
> - Restart your computer
> - Log into the computer with an admin account
> - Make sure you are connected to the internet
> - Download a fresh version of Qustodio from here: http://www.qustodio.com/family/download
> - Follow the installation steps provided.
>
> Then, please make sure to install the very last updates of Windows and of your web browser and
>   restart your computer. If everything works fine then, you should be
>   able to reinstall the antivirus safely.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened on my kids computer. Games other than minecraft, like Battlefield 4 and PVZ are also affected. Once I noticed the SSL error, and realizing that qustodio intercepts SSL traffic to perform a MITM "attack", I uninstalled qustodio. With qustodio gone, everything works again. Sadly I just paid for another year of qustodio, and I don't know why they broke it recently, but that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: I've fixed the problem. For anyone who has the same issue, try backing up all your files and then reverting to the old launcher that runs on Java.
> Thanks and have a nice day :)

Moved from body of question